# Добавление фильтра в spring

Tags: java, spring

**Здравствуйте, можете подсказать как добавить еще один фильтр**

```
 @PostMapping ("filter")
    public String filter(@RequestParam String filter, Model model)
    {
        List<Post> posts = postRepositor.findByDolz(filter);
        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
        return "blog-main";
    }
```

есть фильтр по должностям с переменной Dolz, нужно добавить еще такой-же(например по опыту с переменной Opt.
Пытался повторить такую же конструкцию не получилось(

```
 @PostMapping ("filter")
    public String filter(@RequestParam String filter, Model model)
    {
        List<Post> posts1 = postRepositor.findByOpt(filter);
        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
        return "blog-main";
    }
```

Добавлял в существующую конструкцию, также нет

```
 @PostMapping ("filter")
    public String filter(@RequestParam String filter, Model model)
    {
        List<Post> posts = postRepositor.findByDolz(filter);
        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);

        List<Post> posts1 = postRepositor.findByOpt(filter);
        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);

        return "blog-main";
    }
```

Help

Comment: Или как сделать гибкий поиск?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Пытался повторить такую же конструкцию не получилось

В одном классе двух методов с одной сигнатурой быть не может `public String filter(@RequestParam String filter, Model model)`.

> Добавлял в существующую конструкцию, также нет
> Вы ведь два раза перезаписали posts, с одним и тем же значением.

```
List<Post> posts = postRepositor.findByDolz(filter);
model.addAttribute("posts", posts);

List<Post> posts1 = postRepositor.findByOpt(filter);
model.addAttribute("posts", posts); // список по findByDolz
```

Вам необходим фильтр по `dolz` и `opt`, так почему бы не создать `findByDolzAndOpt()`?

Comment: сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно модель не позволяет добавлять два attribute с одним именем.
Проще всего добавить в `postRepositor` метод `findByDolzAndOpt` выполняющий нужный отбор.
Если же нужно выбрать по условию ИЛИ по должности:

```
List<Post> result1 = postRepository.findByDolz(filter);
List<Post> result2 = postRepository.findByOpt(filter);
List<Post> orResult = new ArrayList<>();
orResult.addAll(result1);
orResult.addAll(result2);
model.addAttribute("posts", orResult);
```

Comment: ,брат, спасибо,как мне с тобой связаться, все работает, но он выводит если только полный текст написать должности или опыта, а мне нужно чтобы он по частям тоже мог искать

Comment: С этим вопросом разобрались. Сочини следующий, про поиск по частям.